# Replace a button to its initial position after multiples translate transforms

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, transformation

I have an button which I move, using a storyboard and a translateTransform :

```
_animatedTranslateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
this.RegisterName("slide", _animatedTranslateTransform);
DoubleAnimation slideDown = new DoubleAnimation();
slideDown.By = 20;
slideDown.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(slideDown, "slide");
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideDown, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
```

After some iterations, my button have moved from 60 px, for example. How can I replace it to its initial position ?

I tried this (I set -60 to simplify the explanation) :

```
TranslateTransform t = (TranslateTransform) _button.RenderTransform;
t.Y = -60;
```

But it doesn't work if the animation already occurred once.

Comment: It seems like your animation has an "HoldEnd" behavior. Stop the animation before "Reseting" the position.

Comment: No I want to keep this behavior. The animation is already finished when I try to reset the position.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
To keep future readers from being confused by the back-and-forth below, the correct answer is to do:

```
_button.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
```

---

Original answer:

I would store the original position to be used whenever you want to reset. I don't think there's a concept of the "original state" for a control.

Comment: Yes but my problem is precisely that I don't know how to reset.

Comment: _button.RenderTransform = null; ? EDIT: Actually, I'm dumb, wouldn't that line alone solve your entire problem? I was thinking that the animation was affecting the control's position, and not just modifying a Transform.

Comment: If I set this property to "null" I won't be able to use my storyboard.

Comment: Can you just reinitialize it to be a new TranslateTransform? (I'm realizing that I should have tested this out before answering!)

Comment: I tried this too but I doesn't have any effect, the transformation is still active.

Comment: Actually it is working, I add the previous comment too early.